# Induction proof using Pascal's Identity: $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{i}+....+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

Prove by induction that for all $n ≥ 0$:

$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{i}+....+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$

We should use pascal's identity

Base case:
$n=0$

LHS: $\binom{0}{0}=1$

RHS: $2^0=1$

Inductive step:
Here is where I am get held up. I know Pascal's Identity  $\displaystyle\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom nk+\binom n{k+1}$
and I am looking to prove $n+1$

so do I want to prove : $\binom{k}{0}+\binom{k}{1}+....+\binom{k}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k+1}=2^{k+1}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your induction hypothesis is that

$$\binom{n}0+\binom{n}1+\ldots+\binom{n}n=2^n\;,$$

and you want to prove that

$$\binom{n+1}0+\binom{n+1}1+\ldots+\binom{n+1}{n+1}=2^{n+1}\;.$$

Pascal’s identity allows you to write

$$\begin{align*}\binom{n+1}1&+\binom{n+1}2+\ldots+\binom{n+1}n\\
&=\left(\binom{n}0+\binom{n}1\right)+\left(\binom{n}1+\binom{n}2\right)+\ldots+\left(\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}n\right)\\
&=\binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1+2\binom{n}2+\ldots+2\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}n\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $\dbinom{n+1}0=\dbinom{n+1}{n+1}=1$, so

$$\begin{align*}\binom{n+1}0&+\binom{n+1}1+\ldots+\binom{n+1}{n+1}\\
&=1+\binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1+2\binom{n}2+\ldots+2\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}n+1\\
&=2\binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1+2\binom{n}2+\ldots+2\binom{n}{n-1}+2\binom{n}n\;.
\end{align*}$$

And at that point you’re almost done.

Comment: i am a little confused now

Comment: @Csci319: Can you be a little more specific about what’s confusing you?

Comment: why does it end at 1?

Comment: So I understand Coefficients of $(x + y)^n$ using the pascal's. I just do not understand how to apply it to this proof

Comment: @Csci319: I left off the $\binom{n+1}0$ and $\binom{n+1}{n+1}$ because when you apply Pascal’s identity to them, you get $\binom{n}{-1}$ and $\binom{n}{n+1}$ (among other things), and I wasn’t sure whether you knew that those are defined to be $0$. If you do know that, I can simplify the calculation a little. However, I added them back in for the final calculation, so nothing was lost. \\ This argument has nothing to do with the use of binomial coefficients in the binomial theorem; all you need is Pascal’s identity.

Comment: yeah thanks, I just still need help with my proof

Comment: @Csci319: My answer contains almost the entire proof; only the very last step is missing.

Comment: after $2\binom{n}{n}$ does it equal $2$?

Comment: @Csci319: What do you mean by *after*? The term $2\binom{n}n$ by itself is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to prove the case where $n = k + 1$. According to what you already have, your assumption is in terms of $k$.

Comment: I changed my assumption

Comment: check it one more time, there's something just a bit off.

Comment: I do not see what is wrong